# Should I replace my bushings and brackets with my stabilizer links?

Tags: toyota, camry, swaybar, stability

I have a Toyota Camry ACV40, and during a regular service, I was told to replace the front stabilizer links and bushings.

Looking at the [diagrams](http://www.toyodiy.com/parts/p_J_2007_TOYOTA_CAMRY_ACV40-AEANK_4803.html?hl=48811), I saw there are two clips that are related, I'm going to order the parts online, so I was wondering should I replace the brackets as well?

Part numbers 48824-26210 and 48824-26210.

Comment: I'm looking at your attached list and I can't see the clips that you mentioned. It might help the next person who has the same problem to be specific about which part you're referring to.

Comment: Added part numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bought the clips anyway.

But the mechanic told me that it's not generally needed to replace the metal clips.

Since I bought them, I asked them to replace it anyway.